# postgres: How to select that have every value in a range?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, `test_table` that looks like this:

```
     analysis_date      |      test_num
------------------------+--------------------
 2001-01-01             |                  1
 2001-01-01             |                  2
 2001-01-01             |                  3
 2001-01-02             |                  1
 2001-01-02             |                  2
 2001-01-02             |                  3
 2001-01-03             |                  1
 2001-01-03             |                  2
 2001-01-03             |                  8
```

I only want to select rows in which the analysis date has a value for `test_num` 1, 2, AND 3. The query should not return rows for anlysis_date `2001-01-03`as row for `test_num` = 3 is missing

```
     analysis_date      |      test_num
------------------------+--------------------
 2001-01-01             |                  1
 2001-01-01             |                  2
 2001-01-01             |                  3
 2001-01-02             |                  1
 2001-01-02             |                  2
 2001-01-02             |                  3
```

I am aware of the `BETWEEN` query, but that doesn't guarantee that all the values within the range exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
SELECT * FROM test_table
   WHERE analysis_date 
              IN ( SELECT analysis_date
                         FROM test_table  where test_num IN (1,2,3)
                         group by analysis_date having 
                         count(DISTINCT test_num) = 3
                   )
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=974b948c78d6916fb10d904120a4b258)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` also

```
select * 
  from test_table t
 where exists ( select 1
                  from test_table  
                 where test_num in (1,2,3)
                   and analysis_date = t.analysis_date
                 group by analysis_date 
                having count(distinct test_num) = 3
               )
```

as an alternative to @Kaushik's case.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method if you want the original rows might be three exists:

```
select t.*
from test_table t
where exists (select 1
              from test_table tt
              where tt.analysis_date = t.analysis_date and
                    tt.test_num = 1
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from test_table tt
              where tt.analysis_date = t.analysis_date and
                    tt.test_num = 2
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from test_table tt
              where tt.analysis_date = t.analysis_date and
                    tt.test_num = 3
             );
```

In particular, this can make use of an index on `(analysis_date, test_num)`.

That said, I think I prefer window functions.  Assuming you have no duplicate tests on the same date:

```
select tt.*
from (select tt.*,
             count(*) filter (where test_num in (1, 2, 3)) over (partition by analysis_date) as cnt
      from test_table tt
     ) t
where cnt = 3;
```